# SQL Insert column names as data

Tags: sql, database

Is there a SQL Query to insert the column names from Table A into the rows in Table B?

Comment: What implementation of SQL?  Microsoft SQL Server?  Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: Also you did definitely mean "column names" - Not "column values" as with `Unpivot`?

Comment: Three virtually identical comments within 1 minute shows how important this question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    INSERT INTO B    
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'A'
```

should work...

Answer (score 6):

As column names are essencially strings, yes, you can insert them into other tables.

The harder (and implied) part of the question, is "How do I get a list of columns for a given table", and the answer to that question depends on the database you are using.

Also, in my experience, storing database metadata into your database, can be indicative of design problems.

Comment: +1 for `storing database metadata into your database, can be indicative of design problems.`

Comment: +1 for design comment. I don't know the project here, but I can't think of a reason you'd need to store column names in another table off the top of my head that couldn't be better executed with a better database design.

Comment: @Jimmy, there are some sane scenarios (I've used this for custom database replication), but most of them are a versiong of the [Inner platform effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect)

Comment: I didn't design this database. It was already here when I got here. I am creating a completely dynamic site builder with the existing databases. The images for our site is in one database, and all of the other information is in another database. They are basically linked, but in no way that is logical.

Comment: @SWeko Never heard the name before, but yep, agreed.

Comment: @Matt - **What RDBMS**? Also can I just confirm that you definitely mean column names rather than column values?

Comment: @Matt: It happens. Just remember that "completely dynamic" can be synonymous with "completely useless". Anyway, for Oracle use the `describe` answer, for SQL Server and (IIRC) MySQL use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA answer.

Comment: @Martin Yes it is the database column names, and not values.

Comment: @SWeko We have a site with a bunch of banks, and they all have their own Virtual Directory. 95% of the banks have a copy and paste site, as they are all different "Virtual Directories". What I did was create a "Generic" site that pulls all of the banks information based off of the virtual directory, and builds the page dynamically. We have a "Website builder" where we can choose all of the values on the page that we want.

Answer (score 2):

(Using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for an attempt at maximum portability)

```
INSERT INTO B
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='A' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='FOO'
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be different depending on your actual software, but for MySQL this should work:

```
 INSERT INTO table_b (col_name)
     SELECT Field FROM (DESCRIBE table_a)
```

- [DESCRIBE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html)